# Xamarin AndroidX how do you reference FragmentCompat now?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, androidx

While using Xamarin and AndroidX, how do I now reference FragmentCompat?

As I see in the Android mappings, one should use AndroidX.Legacy.App.FragmentCompat, but this doesn't seem to exist in Xamarin.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had found the information about the package and found that the package of it in the native android was support.v13.

The official document:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v13

So you can open the nuget package manager and search the package named Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V13. And then you can use the AndroidX.Legacy.App.FragmentCompat after adding the reference of the package.

Comment: That .V13 package requires:   NU1202: Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V13 1.0.0.12 is not compatible with monoandroid11.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V13 1.0.0.12 supports:
  - monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)     How do you get MonoAndroid v12 on?   The Tools->Android->SDK Manager does not have it listed.

Comment: oh, I see the Android SDK Manager has an option for "full unsupported list."  Selecting this gave me the v12 option.  Trying it out now.

Comment: This is caused by the version of xamarin.android is too low, you can update it or use the low version of the Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V13 such as 1.0.0.8.@karhukoti

Comment: In addition，I had updated my visual studio to the version 2022 17.0.0 and the default version of xamarin.android in it was 12.0. You can set the TargetFramework as Android 12.0 when you double click the property of the solution.

Comment: Had you solved your problem?@karhukoti

Comment: Yes - the solution was to reference the 1.0.0.10 version of Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V13 - this then does not required monoandroid 12.0.  Unfortunately, if you go to monoandroid 12 you then need Java11 and then this breaks the xaml viewer (as denoted on the MS page).